# How to change atribute value for all products in one category

Tags: magento

let me first explain my problem, I need to change my atribute for free shipping for all the products in a single category. I know how to read atribute value, because I am displaying banner when a product has a free shipping atribute.

Now, what if I have to set these atribute values for all products in a single category?

What will be the best way to achieve that?

It would be very usefull if, I could change values from backend.

I have found, that you can add an atribute for a category, but sometimes, those atributes won't be the same.

I am using Magento 1.9.2

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to make filter products by category n admin panel. Simple script will make this

```
<?php
require 'app/Mage.php';

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id)
 ->getProductCollection()
 ->addAttributeToSelect('*') // add all attributes - optional
 ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1) // enabled
 ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4); //visibility in catalog,search
foreach($products as $product) {
   $product->setAttribute('new value');
   $product->save();
}
```

Just create new php file, put it in main Magento diroctory and run by cli or url.